# BSONDocument to JsObject and override BSONDateTimeFormat

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I use ReactiveMongo 0.11.11 for Play 2.5 and want to convert a BSONDocument to a JsObject.

For most BSON data types (String, Int...) the defaults are perfectly fine to let the library do the job. For BSON type DateTime (`BSONDateTime`) the value of the JSON property does not give me the format I need.

The JSON value for a Date is a JsObject with property name `$date` and a UNIX timestamp in milliseconds as its value:

```
{
    "something": {
        "$date": 1462288846873
    }
}
```

The JSON I want is a String representation of the Date like this:

```
{
    "something": "2016-05-03T15:20:46.873Z"
}
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to override the default behaviour without rewriting everything or changing code in the library itself.

This is where I think it happens ([source code](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Reactivemongo-Play-Json/blob/master/src/main/scala/package.scala#L220)):

```
val partialWrites: PartialFunction[BSONValue, JsValue] = {
    case dt: BSONDateTime => Json.obj("$date" -> dt.value)
}
```

My version would have to look like this:

```
val partialWrites: PartialFunction[BSONValue, JsValue] = {
    case dt: BSONDateTime =>
        JsString(Instant.ofEpochMilli(dt.value).toString)
}
```

Is it possible to override this bit?

I have created an experiment...

```
import java.time.Instant
import play.api.libs.json._
import reactivemongo.bson._
import reactivemongo.play.json.BSONFormats.BSONDocumentFormat

object Experiment {

    // Original document (usually coming from the database)
    val bson = BSONDocument(
        "something" -> BSONDateTime(1462288846873L) // equals "2016-05-03T15:20:46.873Z"
    )

    // Reader: converts from BSONDateTime to JsString
    implicit object BSONDateTimeToJsStringReader extends BSONReader[BSONDateTime, JsString] {
        def read(bsonDate: BSONDateTime): JsString = {
            JsString(Instant.ofEpochMilli(bsonDate.value).toString)
        }
    }

    // Reader: converts from BSONDateTime to JsValue
    implicit object BSONDateTimeToJsValueReader extends BSONReader[BSONDateTime, JsValue] {
        def read(bsonDate: BSONDateTime): JsValue = {
            JsString(Instant.ofEpochMilli(bsonDate.value).toString)
        }
    }

    // Read and print specific property "something" using the `BSONReader`s above
    def printJsDate = {
        val jsStr: JsString = bson.getAs[JsString]("something").get
        println(jsStr) // "2016-05-03T15:20:46.873Z"

        val jsVal: JsValue = bson.getAs[JsValue]("something").get
        println(jsVal) // "2016-05-03T15:20:46.873Z"
    }

    // Use ReactiveMongo's default format to convert a BSONDocument into a JsObject
    def printAsJsonDefault = {
        val json: JsObject = BSONDocumentFormat.writes(bson).as[JsObject]
        println(json) // {"something":{"$date":1462288846873}}
        // What I want: {"something":"2016-05-03T15:20:46.873Z"}
    }

}
```

I'd like to note that the BSONDateTime conversion to JsValue should always work when I convert a BSONDocument to JsObject, not only when I manually pick a specific known property. This means the property "something" in my example could have any name and also appear in a sub-document.

BTW: In case you wonder, I generally work with BSON collections in my Play project, but I don't think it makes a difference in this case anyway.

**Edit**

I've tried providing a `Writes[BSONDateTime]`, but unfortunately it's not being used and I still get the same result as before. Code:

```
import java.time.Instant
import play.api.libs.json._
import reactivemongo.bson.{BSONDocument, BSONDateTime}

object MyImplicits {
    implicit val dateWrites = Writes[BSONDateTime] (bsonDate =>
        JsString(Instant.ofEpochMilli(bsonDate.value).toString)
    )

    // I've tried this too:
//  implicit val dateWrites = new Writes[BSONDateTime] {
//      def writes(bsonDate: BSONDateTime) = JsString(Instant.ofEpochMilli(bsonDate.value).toString)
//  }
}

object Experiment {
    // Original document (usually coming from the database)
    val bson = BSONDocument("something" -> BSONDateTime(1462288846873L))

    // Use ReactiveMongo's default format to convert a BSONDocument into a JsObject
    def printAsJson = {
        import reactivemongo.play.json.BSONFormats.BSONDocumentFormat
        import MyImplicits.dateWrites // import is ignored

        val json: JsObject = BSONDocumentFormat.writes(bson).as[JsObject]
        //val json: JsValue = Json.toJson(bson) // I've tried this too
        println(json) // {"something":{"$date":1462288846873}}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for any type, the BSON value are converted to Play JSON using [instances of `Writes[T]`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson#using-writes-converters).

There you needs to provide in the implicit scope your own `Writes[BSONDateTime]`.

```
import reactivemongo.bson._
import play.api.libs.json._

object MyImplicits {
  implicit val dateWrites = Writes[BSONDateTime] { date =>
    ???
  }

  def jsonDoc(doc: BSONDocument) = 
    JsObject(bson.elements.map(elem => elem._1 -> myJson(elem._2)))

  implicit val docWrites = OWrites[BSONDocument](jsonDoc)

  def myJson(value: BSONValue): JsValue = value match {
    case BSONDateTime(value) = ???
    case doc @ BSONDocument(_) => jsonDoc(doc)
    case bson => BSONFormats.toJSON(bson)
  }
}

/* where needed */ import MyImplicits.dateWrites
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have implemented a `Writes[BSONDateTime]` like you suggested, but it seems to be ignored. See the Edit in my question. I somehow feel that's because I use `BSONDocumentFormat`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try `println(s"writer = ${implicitly[Writes[BSONDateTime]]}")`

Comment: Prints: `writer = play.api.libs.json.Writes$$anon$6@b9c81b0`